# Is it possible to generate a build of a .NET App hosted on an Azure instance?

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013

Current App and website environment;
ASP.NET app written in C# hosted on a Windows web server and linked to from a site hosted on a SharePoint 2010 server.

Purpose of App;
Download link calls a downloader that generates a custom signed build of the app and logs the download to a SharePoint list.

Site has been redesigned and migrating to SharePoint 2013, looking at a provider-hosted solution for the ASP.NET app and I was wondering if it is possible to generate a build with/on an Azure solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Yes is possible.

The only thing which you have remember is add in your App a clientWebPart. And configure it with url to your asp.net site.

Because when you add your app in page, you must go add how Client App Part or WebPart.